# How to debug a scroll block in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, debugging, scroll

I'm using `scrollIntoView()`, but the behaviour is the same for `scrollTo(...)` and even `location = '#...`.

When I use a timeout > 500ms for the scrolling action it works. Something must be interfering with the programmatic scrolling.

**How can I debug this?**
Is there some information about the scroll event and what's blocking it in the developer console?

**Update**
Just found out that the behaviour still works as expected with the current version of Edge. The problem only occurs in Chrome currently.

---

PS: When clicking a button which has as href `#...`, the scrolling works also. Somehow, the user event goes through without the need for a timeout.

Comment: A common way to debug this is to cut down the app to the minimum that still reproduces the problem. If a bit you've cut out fixes the problem, put it back in and cut something else or a smaller piece out. If at the end of this process, the reason doesn't reveal itself, add more information to the post so that readers can reproduce the problem without using your server. Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

traktor's response was great! But also keep in mind javascript has a unique statement called debugger. it'll pause your code at the line, allowing you to use your browser inspect tool to look at the outputs if you used and console.log('example'); etc.

```
let createUser = () => {
    let user = 'admin';
    let pass = 'password';
    console.log(user, pass);
    debugger; // Program pauses here.
    let userAndPass = user + ' ' + pass;
    console.log(userAndPass)
}
```

Hope this helps! debuggers been a life saver for some of my projects honestly being able to stop the code can be so incredibly useful! :)